# Return winning cell coordinates in JS Connect-Four

Tags: javascript, arrays, 2d-games

I'm working on a JS connect-four game. My 'board' is an array of arrays dimensions 7 * 6 (0 = empty, 1 = occupied by player A, -1 = occupied by player B).

```
var boardTwo = [[1,1,1,1,0,0],[-1,-1,-1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]];
```

This is my (long-winded) function for checking wins (has either player created an unbroken horizontal, vertical, or diagonal line length 4 in the board). How can I modify this so that It returns an array with the coordinates of the winning counters rather than simply an alert message? I appreciate the best solution may involve abandoning my original checkWin function in place of something more concise.

```
checkWin = function(board){
    checkVert(board);
    checkHoriz(board);
    checkDia(board);
    }
winAlert = function(checkSum){
    if(checkSum == 4){
        status = "a"
        alert("a wins"); 
    }
    else if(checkSum == -4){
        status = 'b';
        alert("b wins"); 
    }
}
checkVert = function(board){
    for(var i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
       for(var j = 0; j < board[0].length - 3; j++){
           var checkSum = board[i][j] + board[i][j+1] + board[i][j+2] + board[i][j+3];
           winAlert(checkSum);
           }
    }
}

checkHoriz = function(board){
    for(var i = 0; i < board.length-3; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++){
        var checkSum = board[i][j] + board[i+1][j] + board[i+2][j] + board[i+3][j];
        winAlert(checkSum);
      }
    }
  }

checkDia = function(board){
    for(var i = 0; i < board.length-3; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j < board[0].length - 3; j++){
        var checkSum = board[i][j] + board[i+1][j+1] + board[i+2][j+2] + board[i+3][j+3];
    winAlert(checkSum);
        }
      }
    }
checkWin(boardTwo) //alerts "player A wins"
```

I want checkWin(boardTwo) to return [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3]];

Comment: I started working on an answer to this, but I ended up making a simple working version of the game. When I got back over here, I see that you've already marked an answer. But I figured I'd go ahead and put my code up anyway since I got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an straightforward solution:

- `winAlert` should return a number if someone won, e.g. 1 for A and -1 for B
- Each `check` function will check this result and if it's -1 or 1 then it'll interpolate the values it checked
- if a `check` method returns something that's not undefined i.e. the array with the answer then other checks should not be made
- finally `state` holds who won (`-1, 1 or undefined`) and the returning value of `checkWin` will be an array of arrays if someone won

I also did an additional check on the `checkDiagonal` method to also check the other diagonal that exists in the matrix

```js
function sgn(x) {
  if (x < 0) return -1;
  if (x > 0) return 1;
  return 0;
}

function interpolate(from, to) {
  var coordinates = [];
  var startX = from[0];
  var startY = from[1];
  var limit = Math.max(
    Math.abs(from[0] - to[0]),
    Math.abs(from[1] - to[1])
  ) + 1;
  for (i = 0; i < limit; i += 1) {
    coordinates.push([
      startX + i * sgn(to[0] - from[0]),
      startY + i * sgn(to[1] - from[1])
    ]);
  }
  return coordinates;
}

var state;
function checkWin(board) {
  var ans;
  ans = ans || checkVert(board);
  ans = ans || checkHoriz(board);
  ans = ans || checkDia(board);
  return ans;
}

function winAlert(checkSum) {
  if (Math.abs(checkSum) === 4) {
    state = sgn(checkSum);
    return state;
  }
}

checkVert = function(board) {
  for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < board[0].length - 3; j++) {
      var checkSum = board[i][j] + board[i][j + 1] + board[i][j + 2] + board[i][j + 3];
      if (winAlert(checkSum)) {
        return interpolate([i, j], [i, j + 3]);
      }
    }
  }
}

checkHoriz = function(board) {
  for (var i = 0; i < board.length - 3; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
      var checkSum = board[i][j] + board[i + 1][j] + board[i + 2][j] + board[i + 3][j];
      if (winAlert(checkSum)) {
        return interpolate([i, j], [i + 3, j]);
      }
    }
  }
}

checkDia = function(board) {
  for (var i = 0; i < board.length - 3; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < board[0].length - 3; j++) {
      var checkSum = board[i][j] + board[i + 1][j + 1] + board[i + 2][j + 2] + board[i + 3][j + 3];
      if (winAlert(checkSum)) {
        return interpolate([i, j], [i + 3, j + 3]);
      }
    }
  }
  
  // missing diagonal
  for (i = 3; i < board.length; i += 1) {
    for (var j = 0; j < board[0].length - 3; j++) {
      var checkSum = board[i][j] + board[i - 1][j + 1] + board[i - 2][j + 2] + board[i - 3][j + 3];
      if (winAlert(checkSum)) {
        return interpolate([i, j], [i - 3, j + 3]);
      }
    }
  }
}

var board = [
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [-1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

var ans = checkWin(board) || [];
document.write(state + '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(ans) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about the other diagonal and your solution works well.

Comment: no problem, I'd use a hardcoded array holding the movements instead of multiple loops instead, e.g. `movements = [ [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, -1], [1, 1] ]` and a single triple nested loop

Answer (score 1):

I see now there is already an answer to this. I guess I should've come back over here sooner. I have been working on a version of this as well in JSFiddle. See the link for a working (albeit simple) version of the game: http://jsfiddle.net/42tfrsva/2/

This is not a representation of a physical version of the game, where you have to start at the bottom and work your way up. However, the 'checkScore()` method would be the same in either case to scan the board for wins. In this case, the method returns the checkbox elements that make up the line, but it could be easily modified to return the coordinates of each cell also.

Code - HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="player">Player 1</div>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Code - CSS

```
.player1 {
    background-color: red;
}

.player2 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.winner {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Code - JS

```
var player = 1;

//Set up check events
var cbs = checkboxes();
for (var t = 0; t < cbs.length; t++){
    cbs[t].onclick = checkClick;
}

//Set up reset event
$id("reset").onclick = resetClick;

function resetClick() {
    var cbs = checkboxes();
    for (var c = 0; c < cbs.length; c++) {
        cbs[c].checked = false;
        cbs[c].value = 0;
        cbs[c].parentNode.className = "";
    }
    player = 1;
    $html("player", "Player 1");
}

//create functions
function $id(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

function $tags(tag, parent) {
    parent = (parent) ? parent : document;
    return parent.getElementsByTagName(tag);
}

function $html(id, html) {
    var el = $id(id);
    if (el) el.innerHTML = html;
}

function checkboxes() {
    var tags = $tags("input");
    var cbs = [];
    for (var t = 0; t < tags.length; t++) {
        if (tags[t].type == "checkbox")
            cbs.push(tags[t]);
    }
    return cbs;
}

function checkClick(e) {
    if (!e || !e.target || !e.target.parentNode
       || e.target.value != "0") {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    e.target.parentNode.className = "player" + player;
    e.target.value = player;

    var path = checkScore();
    if (path.length == 4) {
        alert("Winner player " + player + "!");
        for (var p = 0; p < path.length; p++)
            path[p].parentNode.className = "winner";
    }

    player = (player == 1) ? 2 : 1;
    $html("player", "Player " + player);
}

function valueArray() {
    var values = [];
    var cbs, trs = $tags("tr", $tags("table")[0]);

    for (var t = 0; t < trs.length; t++) {
        cbs = $tags("input", trs[t]);
        var cbarr = [];

        for (var c = 0; c < cbs.length; c++) {
            cbarr.push(cbs[c].value*1);
        }
        values.push(cbarr);
    }

    return values;
}

function cbArray() {
    var values = [];
    var cbs, trs = $tags("tr", $tags("table")[0]);

    for (var t = 0; t < trs.length; t++) {
        cbs = $tags("input", trs[t]);
        var cbarr = [];

        for (var c = 0; c < cbs.length; c++) {
            cbarr.push(cbs[c]);
        }
        values.push(cbarr);
    }

    return values;
}

function checkScore() {
    var path = [];
    var values = valueArray();
    var cbs = cbArray();

    //check up/down
    for (var r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
        for (var c = 0; c < 7; c++) {
            if (values[r][c] == player && values[r+1][c] == player &&
                values[r+2][c] == player && values[r+3][c] == player) {
                path = new Array(
                    cbs[r][c], cbs[r+1][c],
                    cbs[r+2][c], cbs[r+3][c]
                );
                return path;
            }
        }
    }

    //check left/right
    for (var r = 0; r < 6; r++) {
        for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            if (values[r][c] == player && values[r][c+1] == player &&
                values[r][c+2] == player && values[r][c+3] == player) {
                path = new Array(
                    cbs[r][c], cbs[r][c+1],
                    cbs[r][c+2], cbs[r][c+3]
                );
                return path;
            }
        }
    }

    //check right diagonal
    for (var r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
        for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            if (values[r][c] == player && values[r+1][c+1] == player &&
                values[r+2][c+2] == player && values[r+3][c+3] == player) {
                path = new Array(
                    cbs[r][c], cbs[r+1][c+1],
                    cbs[r+2][c+2], cbs[r+3][c+3]
                );
                return path;
            }
        }
    }

    //check left diagonal
    for (var r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
        for (var c = 3; c < 7; c++) {
            if (values[r][c] == player && values[r+1][c-1] == player &&
                values[r+2][c-2] == player && values[r+3][c-3] == player) {
                path = new Array(
                    cbs[r][c], cbs[r+1][c-1],
                    cbs[r+2][c-2], cbs[r+3][c-3]
                );
                return path;
            }
        }
    }

    return path;
}
```

I realized that you don't have to check every cell. In each of the loops in the `checkScore` method, the row/column loops are limited to the needed cells to get the vertical, horizontal, and diagonal lines.